# Solr query to calculate geo distance between two points

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj

I have latitude and longitude of two business locations and want to calculate the distance between them. How do i do it using solr query.

I got the query to get all the nearest locations from a point ( latitude , longitude ).

But want a query to get distance between two points.

Below is the sample code snippet to get the locations from a point

// sample location

```
location = new double[]{lat, long}; 

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("{!func}geodist()");  
query.set("fq","query");  
query.set("sfield", "location");  
query.set("pt", location );  
query.setSortField("score", ORDER.asc);  
query.setFields("score", "id");  
SolrDocumentList list = solrServer.query(query).getResults();
```

Comment: Have you looked at - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#Returning_the_distance

Comment: i tried this query from there &sort=min(geodist(store,37.7,-122.4),geodist(store,39.7,-105))%20asc

The max distance it gives is 1.0 which is not the actual distance i guess.

Answer (score 0):

To return distance you should add `geodist()` function to `fl` field list query field like that:

```
query.set("fl","*,distance:geodist()")
```

"distance" is the field name to return `geodist()` result in.